# How to play a standard windows sound?

Tags: winapi, audio

How do I find out which sound files the user has configured in the control panel?

Example: I want to play the sound for "Device connected".

Which API can be used to query the control panel sound settings?

I see that there are some custom entries made by third party programs in the control panel dialog, so there has to be a way for these programs to communicate with the global sound settings.

Edit: Thank you. I did not know that PlaySound also just played appropriate sound file when specifying the name of the registry entry.

To play the "Device Conntected" sound:

```
::PlaySound( TEXT("DeviceConnect"), NULL, SND_ALIAS|SND_ASYNC );
```

Comment: Take a look at these articles: [Playing .wav files using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/PlaySounds1.aspx) [Creating Your Own Sound Alerts](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/soundalerts.aspx)

Comment: How/where did you find the appropiate alias name of the sound? I'm looking for example for the "sms received" sound.

Comment: I found a list in the registry at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\EventLabels.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`PlaySound`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms712879(v=vs.85)) is the API.

Also see [Play System Sounds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/using-playsound-to-play-system-sounds).

Answer (score 15):

Not Win32, but for .net anyway, you can do this using the following in C#:

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
// Plays the Asterisk sound (used for Information (i))
// Also available:
// Exclamation (Warning /!\)
// Hand (aka Critical Stop - Error (X))
// Question (?)
// Beep (aka Default Beep)
```

Comment: How about the other system sounds, like "Device connected" or "new mail"?

Comment: @Anthony I don't think you can do that within .net. You'll need to use P/Invoke for that.