# how to play a specific windows error sound in c#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play a standard windows sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167/how-to-play-a-standard-windows-sound)

I want to play an windows error sound in my c# application when the user isn´t allowed to enter more characters into a text box.
Is there a .net framework api or have i to play it from wave files and if, how do i do this?

Comment: are you wanting to play THE error sound or a specific wav file

Comment: when an action is performed which is not allowed, I want to play the classic windows error sound. But when another acion is performed which is not forbidden but also not good I want to play another system sound

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72167/how-to-play-a-standard-windows-sound

Comment: The link you´ve postd is in c++. I know how c++ looks like but I don´t know how to convert into C#

Comment: oh ok... didn´t see first time o.O

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check the [System.Media.SystemSounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143806%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class. I believe `SystemSounds.Hand.Play()` should do the trick.

Comment: Well, I gave an MSDN link, which is the official Microsoft documentation for the thing. If you want an example, [here's a CodeProject page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13327/System-Media-Sound) that showcases this class.